# Paypal integration for Donate button in iOS

Tags: ios, paypal

In my application, I have to implement a donate button with which the user can donate money to a particular organization. I have used the Paypal SDK, in which the sample code shows the purchase of some products.

How can I get an implementation of "Donation" with the Paypal SDK in iOS?

Comment: in my experience, your application will be rejected directly if you implement such button when you want to publish the app via AppStore.

Comment: @holex can u give the reason as you have experienced this.

Comment: I developed an application, I did not want to ask money from the end-users, but I would have preferred to get some donation for making future updates. the Apple rejected the app, saying I cannot collect donations via an iOS app; I can use in-app purchases or a I can set an initial price for the app, but they won't allow to collect donations. eventually I removed the donation button, and the app was approved. that is my experience.

Answer (score 0):

Was the organization in question a nonprofit? If not, it might be considered under the ["Unacceptable" section of the "Other Business Model Issues" portion of the App Store Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#unacceptable):

> (iv) Unless you are an approved nonprofit or otherwise permitted under Section 3.2.1 (vi) above, collecting funds within the app for charities and fundraisers. Apps that seek to raise money for such causes must be free on the App Store and may only collect funds outside of the app, such as via Safari or SMS.